# how to perfectly overlap two (identical) elements?

Tags: javascript, height, google-closure-library, css

Inside a `position:relative`element `box`, I have

1. a absolutely positioned element `parent` at `top:0` with a couple of static `p` and `h1..h6`inside. Those may all have different margin/padding values.
2. a few absolutely positioned elements where element name and content matches exactly one of the elements from above list #1.

The goal is to set the y-value of the 2nd element such that it exactly overlaps with the corresponding one from the set in 1. .

I've taken this approach (using closure, but anything could be used really), starting with an Array of elements `content`for generating list #1:

```
goog.dom.removeChildren(parent);
for (var i=0; i<content.length; i++) {
    offsets.push(parent.offsetHeight);
    goog.dom.appendChild(parent, content[i]);
}
return offsets;
```

Then, using the values from `offsets`:

```
var matchedElm = source[i].cloneNode(true);
goog.style.setStyle(matchedElm, {"top": offsets[i] + "px"});
goog.dom.appendChild(box, matchedElm);
```

Now this works for various paddings and `margin=0`, but fails when margins are non-0 on the `p` and `h1..6`. I have also tried "scrollHeight" but nothing seems to take into account margins.
I've then tried getting `offsetTop` directly from the rendered elements in list #1, but this seems to yield exact same results as above procedure to fill `offsets`.

How can I make the overlap work? I'm looking for a native javascript or closure-library solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for may be `goog.style.getPageOffset` and because your overlapping element is absolutely positioned with a top setting you may have to deduct the top margin of the element you want to overlap using `goog.style.getMarginBox`. Here is some sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>test</title>
</head> 
 <body> 
<div id="game" data-something="hello"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/goog/base.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     goog.require("goog.dom");
     goog.require("goog.style");
 </script>
 </body>
    <div id="contentToOverLap" style="position:absolute;top:30px;left:30px">
        <h1 style="margin:10px;padding:2px">h1 10px mar and 2px pad</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="overlappingContent" style="display:inline">
        <h1 style="color:red;margin:15px;padding:2px;position:absolute">
            h1 15px mar and 2px pa
        </h1>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var pH = goog.dom.$("contentToOverLap").children[0];
            var cH = goog.dom.$("overlappingContent").children[0];
            var box = goog.style.getPageOffset(pH);
            console.log("box is:", box);
            var mar = goog.style.getMarginBox(cH);
            console.log("mar is:", mar);
            var t = box.y - mar.top;
            var l = box.x - mar.left;
            goog.style.setStyle(cH, { "top": t + "px", "left": l + "px" });
        })();
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer works, thank you! Subtracting goog.style.getMarginBox did the trick. But can you explain why subtracting? My intuition was that parent.offsetHeight gives a value too low (lacking margins) and something would have to be added, rather than subtracted?

Comment: @bebbi It looks like setting the top of the overlapping content sets the top of the outer box (including margins). So I set the top to 30px and the margin is 10px then the content will display at 40px. getPageOffset gives you the inner box (top of the content) changing margins will change it's values. I see flaw in my code since I deduct the margin of the content to be overlapped from the top of overlapping content but should use margin of overlapping content, the code works because they're both the same but if they're not it will fail. I have corrected this mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure how getPageOffset is calculated but as mentioned before; it'll give you the location of the content (so it includes margins). I am not using offsetHeight in my code because looking at the source code for getPageOffset to manually calculate an element's location involves too much code to re write. And I'm not sure how to use it anyway :-)

Comment: ok that explanation for how setting the top applies to outer box makes sense! Regarding the calculation of getPageOffset, I can help: it's roughly the lines below for 95% cases and then 90 more lines for the edge cases (sorry, couldn't get the code markup working):
`
    var getPageOffset = function(element) {
        var point = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        var parent = element;
        do {
            point.x += parent.offsetLeft;
            point.y += parent.offsetTop;
        } while (parent = parent.offsetParent);
        return point;
    };
`